# With Twisted, how can 'connectionMade' fire a specific Deferred?

Tags: python, connection, twisted, reactor

This is part of a larger program; I'll explain only the relevant parts.  Basically, my code wants to create a new connection to a remote host.  This should return a Deferred, which fires once the connection is established, so I can send something on it.

I'm creating the connection with `twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorSSL.connectSSL`.  That calls `buildProtocol` on my `ClientFactory` instance to get a new connection (`twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol`) object, and returns a `twisted.internet.interfaces.IConnector`.  When the connection is started, Twisted calls `startedConnecting` on the factory, giving it the `IConnector`.  When the connection is actually made, the protocol's `connectionMade` callback is called, with no arguments.

Now, if I only needed one connection per host/port, the rest would be easy.  Before calling `connectSSL`, I would create a Deferred and put it in a dictionary keyed on (host, port).  Then, in the protocol's connectionMade, I could use `self.transport.getPeer()` to retrieve the host/port, use it to look up the Deferred, and fire its callbacks.  But this obviously breaks down if I want to create more than one connection.

The problem is that I can't see any other way to associate a Deferred I created before calling `connectSSL` with the `connectionMade` later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this some more, I think I've come up with a solution, although hopefully there is a better way; this seems kind of weird.

Twisted has a class, `ClientCreator` that is used for producing simple single-use connections.  It in theory does what I want; connects and returns a `Deferred` that fires when the connection is established.  I didn't think I could use this, though, since I'd lose the ability to pass arguments to the protocol constructor, and therefore have no way to share state between connections.

However, I just realized that the `ClientFactory` constructor does accept `*args` to pass to the protocol constructor.  Or at least it looks like it; there is virtually no documentation for this.  In that case, I can give it a reference to my factory (or whatever else, if the factory is no longer necessary).  And I get back the `Deferred` that fires when the connection is established.